# how to get dataset value from store procedure for oracle in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

my sp returning table in curser but i m getting error while mapping with dataset

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("Size", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = size
command.Parameters.Add("Index", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = Index;
command.Parameters.Add("Data", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(ds);
return ds;
```

But I am getting below error:
How to map it

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.] System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) +130 System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() +105 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3572

Comment: How may records this sp is returning?

Comment: table having 100 records

Comment: I asked about records because one of the possibility of error could be due to MaxHttpCollection which is depend on number of records. Anyways now can we tell on which line your code you are getting the error?

Comment: @Dnyanesh i am getting error on da.fill(ds)

Answer (score 0):

[InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]

There are multiple possibilities for this exception.

1) `command.CommandText = *Your Sp's name will go here*;`
Looks like missing in your code. Give CommandText if missing.

2) In may be because of [MaxHttpCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformatter.maxhttpcollectionkeys(v=vs.118).aspx) setting in web.config. By default it can hold 1000. Add following setting in your web.config.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />
</appSettings>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.